# How to set-up google oauth using django-allauth without the admin panel

Tags: django, django-allauth

Is there a way to set-up google oauth using django-allauth WITHOUT using the admin panel? I am building a website and don't want to use the default django admin app. I've acquired the required Google client id and secret, now I'm not able to understand how to configure the django-allauth SocailApp setting without the admin app.

```
# SETTINGS.py
# Django-allauth config
SITE_ID = 1

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google": {
        "SCOPE": ["profile", "email",],
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {"access_type": "online",},
        "APP": {
            "client_id": env("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
            "secret": env("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"),
        },
    }
}
```

How should I add site to this configuration?

Comment: An afterthought having answered the question: Can you clarify what you mean? Do you mean without having to add a `SocialApp` instance in admin. Or do you mean hiding all of the admin interface from admin users? Or both.

Comment: What I meant was when configuring socialauth, we have to configure the SocialApp, and then add a site to the SocialApp. I couldn't find out how we can add a site to the SocialApp **without** the using the admin panel. As a workaround for now I set the site in a custom migration. It's working, but it's definitely not a proper solution.

Comment: Got it. If you do not have multiple sites, you do not need to add a site to the SocialApp. If you do have multiple sites, it would probably be a bad idea to have those sites referenced in code. Which of the two situations are you in. If the later, why do you not want to use the admin?

Comment: I'm in the first situation, i.e. I currently have only 1 site. I checked without setting any site and it worked! But there is a possibility that more sites will be added to the project in the future. I can't use the admin panel as the company I work for doesn't allow it (they have some policy in place for this)

Comment: The real distinction here is between storing your `SocialApp`s on the database, and hard-coding them in settings. If you can't use the django-admin, you can always write your own view that does what the django admin does. Displays, instances of `SocialApp` and allows you to change them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have everything you need already in the question. The 3 valid keys for `APP` are:

- `client_id`
- `secret`
- `key` (which you don't need in your case).

This gives you all the basic set-up you would get by adding your app through the admin interface. The only other things you can add via the admin are `name` and `sites`. Having a scan of the codebase, I can't see where `SocialApp.name` is actually other used, other than `__str__` for `SocialApp`. This just leaves, `sites`.

There are two potential situations I can think of. You have one site, or you have many sites. If you have many, then they will be stored in the database. It would be a very bad idea, to hard code these id's into your codebase, because then if your database changes everything breaks. If you have multiple sites, it would be a much better idea to have your `SocialApp`s also stored in the database to correspond with `Site`s.

To see what happens under the hood, when selecting an app:

```
# allauth.socialaccount.adapter.py

    def get_app(self, request, provider):
        # NOTE: Avoid loading models at top due to registry boot...
        from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp

        config = app_settings.PROVIDERS.get(provider, {}).get('APP')
        if config:
            app = SocialApp(provider=provider)
            for field in ['client_id', 'secret', 'key']:
                setattr(app, field, config.get(field))
        else:
            app = SocialApp.objects.get_current(provider, request)
        return app
```

`app_settings.PROVIDERS` actually returns `settings.SOCIALAUTH_PROVIDERS`.